# How does mongod process inside a docker container allow connections from outside

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am very new to mongodb and i am trying to understand how does connections to the mongod process work.

So in my mac i created a docker container running the mongod process using the below command :

`docker container run -d --name mongod -p 27017:27017 mongo mongod`

Then since my mac has the mongo shell installed i tried connection to the container from inside my shell and it works :

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("4c4c4689-f25b-4edd-9ef2-e0f79307574c") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.1
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-12-30T11:05:16.945+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-12-30T11:05:16.945+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-12-30T11:05:16.945+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-12-30T11:05:17.561+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-12-30T11:05:17.561+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-12-30T11:05:17.561+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-12-30T11:05:17.561+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> exit
```

My question is , as per my understanding the `mongod` process by default binds only to the `localhost` interface so only when i login to the docker container which is running the mongod process i should be able to connect to it.

Just the fact that i have done a port redirection allows me to connect to the container from the outside world . So if my laptop was a server then since i have a container with an exposed port allows me to connect to it from anywhere on the internet ?

I am not sure about whether i am thinking correctly.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mongod process by default binds only to the localhost interface

This is inaccurate. If you look inside the container:

```
root@146bde0f7b81:/# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

mongodb is in fact listening on `0.0.0.0` which means it listens on ALL ip addresses on all interfaces it can. If it was exposed on ONLY localhost then this netstat would have looked like:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Hence you can connect from your host shell using `mongo` as it connects to the host's localhost (127.0.0.1) which is listening and port mapped by docker. If you would inspect the container you would see something like:

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "50616aa4d4ec2925d9fc7ddcaf9f96f32ec2fc2e0c49b19517b86180ee3ebb8d",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "27017/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "27017"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

which tells you that on the host ALL IP addresses on ALL interfaces' port 27017 is port mapped by docker.

> So if my laptop was a server then since i have a container with an exposed port allows me to connect to it from anywhere on the internet ?

No this does not work. The router that acts as an intermediary between your local LAN network and the WAN network (internet) does not allow this. In fact it is blocked at your ISP's network only if someone tries to connect to a public_ip:port

Comment: I understood the part about mongodb in which you said that it is listening for connections on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. But i did not fully understand what you said about docker inspect command and what you wanted to prove regarding it.